# Controlling a Schwartz kernel near the diagonal

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-operators

Let $D$ be a first-order elliptic differential operator that is essentially self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Consider the operator $(D+i)^q$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with domain $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Denote its bounded inverse by
$$(D+i)^{-q}:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
This operator has a Schwartz kernel $k_q$, which can be shown to be continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ if $q$ is large enough, using the Sobolev embedding theorem. In fact, one can show in this case that $k_q$ decays exponentially.

**Question:** Suppose $q=1$. Then is $k_q$ continuous away from the diagonal? If so, do we have any pointwise control on $k_q$ on the complement of the diagonal?